# How to replace the value of multiple columns in a file based on two columns in another file with bash?

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to replace the value of multiple columns in a file using awk. The reason to use awk is that the file is very large and cant do it loading it in memory. I've tried to do with pandas (python).

I have a large database as a textfile. I put here a example of the info in the file (tab-delimited):

```
CHROM   POS    REF     ALT     GT_00  d_GT_00 c_GT_00  de_GT_00  can_GT_00  epi_GT_00
chr1    10      T       A       7       1       1        2           5       7
chr1    10      T       A       7       1       1        3           0       1
chr1    10      T       G       7       2       1        1           8       2
chr1    11      None    None    2       0       0        0           5       4
chr1    11      G       T       2       1       0        0           2       3
```

If the first two columns (CHROM,POS) are the same in the rows, I have to sum the values of the columns that contain  '_00' in the header.

So, the expected output, is:

```
 CHROM   POS    REF     ALT     GT_00   d_GT_00  c_GT_00  de_GT_00  can_GT_00 epi_GT_00
 chr1    10      T       A       21       4       3           6       13       10      
 chr1    10      T       A       21       4       3           6       13       10
 chr1    10      T       G       21       4       3           6       13       10
 chr1    11      None    None     4       1       0           0       7         7
 chr1    11      G       T        4       1       0           0       7         7
```

I dont know how to do this, because I'm very new in programing, so, I have to do the following with this `awk` code.

```
 awk -F'\t' 'FNR==1{next};
   {keys[$1"\t"$2]
     for (i=5;i<=10;i++)
   {sum[$1"\t"$2, i] += $i}
   }END {for (key in keys) { printf "%s", key
   for (i=5;i<=10;i++) {printf "%s%s", "\t", sum[key,i]}  printf "\n"}} OFS='\t' out.txt
```

With this code, and using as 'out.txt' the first textfile, I get:

```
 chr1    10      21      4       3       6       13      10
 chr1    11      4       1       0       0       7       7
```

Now, I'm trying to replace, in the rows with `chr1 10`, the 6 values in the first row, and in the rows with  `chr1 11`, the 6 values in the second row.

I have accomplished to change the value in one column with the this code:

```
 awk -F"\t" 'NR==FNR{h[$1"\t"$2]=$3;next}
 {
   printf $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"h[$1"\t"$2]"\t";
   for (i=6;i<=NF;i++)
   {printf "%s",$i "\t"};
    printf "\n"
  }' OFS="\t" file1 file2
```

but need to do the same for all the columns.

How can I do it using a similar code?

Note: I have more columns that doesn't have '_00' in the header name

Comment: Well, if you have [datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/), try this `datamash -H -g1,2 collapse 3,4 sum 5-10 <your_file`

Comment: @oguzismail thanks for the answer! I have tried it and it seems to sum only two of the three values for chr1 10

Comment: @oguzismail Forget what i have said, I kept -H when using a file without header. It works perfectly! Is there a way to undo the collapse and get all the rows with the final summed value?

Comment: I don't know datamash very well but you can undo the collapse using awk, just pipe datamash's output to `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {j=split($3,a,",");split($4,b,",");for(i=1;i<=j;++i){$3=a[i];$4=b[i];print}}'`

Comment: Hi again @oguzismail! Do you know if it is possible to do the split on a range of columns? In my real data, I have ~ 80 columns to collapse, and its very dirty and not elegant to write `split($n,a,",") and $n=a[i]` 80 times. Im trying to nest two for loops:  1. To iterate over the collapsed columns , 2. To iterate over the values into the array 'a', but cant get the desire result

Answer (score 0):

here you go with a memory efficient perl on-liner which should solve your problem. You may need to add the correct input filed separator e.g. `-F'\t'` and a regex to skip comment lines.

```
perl -lane 'if(!$prev || $prev eq "$F[0]:$F[1]"){push @r,[@F[4..$#F]]; push @snp,join"\t",@F[0..3]}else{for $r (@r){$o[$_]+=$$r[$_] for 0..scalar(@$r)-1}; print join"\t",($_,@o) for @snp; @snp=(join"\t",@F[0..3]); @o=(); @r=([@F[4..$#F]])} $prev="$F[0]:$F[1]"; END{for $r (@r){$o[$_]+=$$r[$_] for 0..scalar(@$r)-1}; print join"\t",($_,@o) for @snp;}' < \ 
<(echo -e "chr1 10 A T 1 2 3\nchr1 10 A G 1 2 3\nchr1 11 A T 4 5 6\nchr2 12 G C 7 8 9")
```

formatted version with comments for you :)

```
if(!$prev || $prev eq "$F[0]:$F[1]"){ # CHROM:POS compare to previous line
    push @r,[@F[4..$#F]]; # store values in array of array reference
    push @snp,join"\t",@F[0..3] # store CHROM,POS,REF,ALT
}else{
    for $r (@r){ # CHROM:POS is new
        $o[$_]+=$$r[$_] for 0..scalar(@$r)-1 # sum up values in array references
    };
    print join"\t",($_,@o) for @snp; # join CHROM,POS,REF,ALT with summed values
    @snp=(join"\t",@F[0..3]); # re-initialize
    @o=();
    @r=([@F[4..$#F]])
} 
$prev="$F[0]:$F[1]"; # store CHROM:POS info
END{ # print final lines
    for $r (@r){
        $o[$_]+=$$r[$_] for 0..scalar(@$r)-1
    };
    print join"\t",($_,@o) for @snp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @pyr0 ! I will take look. I have never written perl code and its very difficult to me to understand it

Comment: thank you very much for the comments! Do i have to replace the `#` before the F in the second line?

Comment: `F` is a builtin array variable initialized as `@F` by the `-a` switch and accessible via `$F[0]`, `$F[1]`, similar to `$1`, `$2`, .. in awk. `$#` is a builtin perlvar to get the last index of an array e.g. `$#F` For more see https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html